# tollPass and toll calculation in Norway using the fleet API

Tags: here-api

I am using https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json to calculate a route in Norway including toll costs. This is working. However, there is a toll pass in Norway, AutoPASS, and I can't get the calculation to use this parameter.

I have tried:
...&tollpass=AutoPASS
...&tollpass=Annual,AutoPASS,EasyGO
...&tollpass=Senior_Pass,transponder,Annual,Nr_of_Days,Nr_of_Months,SunPass,E-Z Pass,AutoPASS,EasyGo

I get 91 EUR, or 88 EUR when transponder is set in tollpass.
Using this: https://www.fjellinjen.no/privat/bompengekalkulator/ I can see that without a toll pass the fee is 962 NOK which equals 91 EUR. With the toll pass the fee equals 446 NOK which equals 42 EUR.

How do you get the toll cost using the Norwegian AutoPASS?

I have removed my API key from the following link:
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=59.08597,11.24958&waypoint1=59.94091,10.97901&waypoint2=59.08597,11.24958&rollups=none,country;tollsys&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&length=17m&commercial=1&limitedWeight=40t&height=4m&currency=EUR&tollVehicleType=3&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&vehicleNumberAxles=3&trailerNumberAxles=2&tollPass=AutoPASS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below request is working with tollPass=AutoPass, we are getting 44.92 EUR:

https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=59.08597,11.24958&waypoint1=59.94091,10.97901&waypoint2=59.08597,11.24958&rollups=none,country;tollsys&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&length=17m&commercial=1&limitedWeight=40t&height=4m&currency=EUR&tollVehicleType=3&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&vehicleNumberAxles=3&trailerNumberAxles=2&tollPass=AutoPass

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but .. where does one register for credentials for this API?